# How to interact with a web page (read/write programmatically) that only opens inside specific software

Tags: javascript, html, bots

**CONTEXT**

I use a web application that only works with IE8 for customer management.
So I developed an `AutoIt` `script` to do the job. It works great and my company prosper.

But recently the company that owns this web application, announced that the only way to access this web application will be through a new web browser, that was developed specifically to work with this application.

This new browser doesn't have developer tools to show codes like HTML, JavaScript, CSS, etc. So my bot will not work properly, because I need to read and write to this page, I cannot rely only in the ***X,Y coordinates***,  because data it's always changing, dropdowns, confirmation/error pop-ups, etc.

**QUESTION**

How can I interact (read/write) with this web application?

- **Read from (main page and popup):**
  Textbox, select, radiobutton, checkbox, etc.
- **Write/Simulate Click/ to (main page and popup):**
  Textbox, select, radiobutton, checkbox, , etc.

**NOTE**

- It's not mandatory the solution work with **AutoIt**, I accept any solution as long as it works (read/write).
- The browser name is **ASCWebBrowser**, but you will not be able to download it, because it's only for the owners business partners.

I don't have a clue, about which tag include.